# In Python matplotlib, why isn't adding a color bar changing the color of a surface?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I've been experimenting with the color bar in Python Matplotlib for 3-d surfaces, but I can't get it to actually color-code the corresponding surface.  The code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from matplotlib import cm
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
x = np.linspace(0, 1600, 1600)
y = np.linspace(0, 1600, 1600)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
j = 10*X+10*Y
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, j)
fig.colorbar(surf)
```

generates this figure:

[image]/

As you can see, the Colorbar does nothing to color the actual shape, and the axis bounds for the colorbar (0 to 1) are nonsensical for the bar's shape.  Out of the various fixes I've seen in code online that appear to generate a proper scale, none have worked.  Most (such as adding "vmin" and "vmax" arguments in various places) have either done nothing or generated errors.  The only thing that has done anything different is the following code, adding a "ticks" argument to the colorbar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from matplotlib import cm
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
x = np.linspace(0, 1600, 1600)
y = np.linspace(0, 1600, 1600)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
j = 10*X+10*Y
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, j)
fig.colorbar(surf, ticks=np.linspace(0, 32000,32))
```

This code instead generates this graph,

[image: this graph]

which now does not have an upper axis bound at all for the colorbar, and in which the color of the surface is not changed.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colorbar` command does not color your surface plot. It is `plot_surface` command that does. You can just pass `cmap` into `plot_surface`:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, j, cmap='viridis')
```

Output:

[image]